# What function should be defined here

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error `Undefined class '_'` after dart null safety migration. The issue is with this `as FutureOr<List<Sections>> Function(_)` added to his piece of code I took from [fetch data from the internet](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) What should I replace the `Function(_)` with?

The migrated code that produces error:

```
Future<List<Sections>> fetchWikiSections(String url) async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return compute(parseWikiSections as FutureOr<List<Sections>> Function(_), response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed!');
  }
}

List<Sections>? parseWikiSections(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json
      .decode(responseBody)['remaining']['sections']
      .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<Sections>((json) => Sections.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

Comment: `parseWikiSections` takes a `String` argument, so that should be the argument type.  However, why do you even need the explicit `as` cast?  Can you remove it?

Comment: Hi @jamesdlin thank you. It was added automatically by `dart migrate` command. Of course I could remove it, but I just want to understand what it would do and what to replace the `Function(_)` with.

Comment: The migration tool sometimes does not make optimal changes.  If your code passes analysis without the cast, you should remove it.